# setting div to position: fixed on scroll with jquery causes content below to jump up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you scroll down, the top bar goes up and the moment the top bar gets out of sight, the header gets set to `position: fixed;`.  The moment this happens, the content below takes a massive jump upward with 1 scroll wheel click.

I'm assuming its probably something simple I'm overlooking, but wanted to check to see if someone else saw the issue.  I've looked through it, but can't really see whats happening right off.

I've set up a jsfiddle to show this code in full.

http://jsfiddle.net/yZVjU/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#header");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        //$("#header_left").html("Distance from top:" + pos.top + "<br />Scroll position: " + windowpos);
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#header { float: left; width: 100%; height: 60px; background: #fff; }
#header_left { float: left; display: inline; width: 650px; height: 100px; }
#header_right { float: right; display: inline; width: 200px; height: 100px; text-align: right; }


.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    /*_top: expression( ie6 = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px") );*/
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

If you get to the position where the header gets set to fixed, and click up and down, you'll see where the content below is jumping more than 1 click.

Comment: 1- So the problem happens when the class "stick" is added?
2-pls explain : "the content below takes a massive jump upward with 1 mouse click."

Comment: thats what it appears.  But it may be an issue with styling as well.  When position fixed gets added, the content below jumps up.  So I'm really curious if I'm missing something in the styling.  It doesn't appear to be an issue with the jquery as far as I can tell.

Comment: So, image clicking the down button once to scroll the page down slightly.  When you click this and "stick" gets added, the content below jumps up more than it should.  It's like a style is off or something and the content goes higher than it should which causes the page to look weird during that transition.  My mouse click (I mean using scroll wheel and clicking it once)

Comment: Why don't you fix the header with CSS by default? It seems you're trying to fix the header on scrolling the page.

Comment: I wanted the topbar to disappear and the header to move up and stick to the top for the rest of the page.  Which is why jquery is changing it to stick class and the content continues scrolling up, but the header stays at top the entire time.

Comment: Cuz it seems your header is not taking space of the page any more, as if it were removed. So you need to make it sticky, and at the same time occupy space.

Comment: As you scroll down, the white space gets smaller.  The part that disappears is the topbar, and the white part that is left is the header.  Image on left, and a link on the right is the header.  Below that is a silver section (which symbolizes the content and how it scrolls behind the white part position: fixed;

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/yZVjU/2/ for a colored demonstration of what is happening.  I changed the colors of each section.  The black is the topbar that disappears, the red is the header that gets set the fixed.  If you look at the word "design" below that in the silver, the moment the header gets set to fixed, it jumps up behind.  It looks like it jumps up like 50 pixels or so when it should barely move.

Comment: Fixed positioning takes an element out of the flow, the same way as absolute positioning does – and that’s why the content “jumps” up as soon as you set fixed, because the header is “not there any more” for the content to keep it where it was before. Easiest solution: Position the header absolute by default (and keep the content at bay by a padding/margin of header height), and then switch it to fixed when the page is scrolled.

Comment: ahh thanks CBroe. I reread what you said mohammed about not taking space and I get it now.  Sorry.  I simply added `$("body").css("margin-top", 60);` and it fixed the issue.  Thanks everyone!  Can someone add an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set an element to `Position Fixed`, it stops taking space anymore from the document since it will be like-floating around. Therefore the rest of `DOM` will jump up as if that element was suddenly deleted.

Add an empty div and before you set `Position to Fixed`, fill in that div with empty space, or allocate more space for `document` to occupy.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't even think of that before.  I simply added `if (windowpos >= pos.top) { s.addClass("stick"); $("body").css("margin-top", 60); } else { s.removeClass("stick"); $("body").css("margin-top", 0); }` and it fixed the issue.

Comment: @kdjernigan your solution helped me out. Thanks a lot.