# page jumps when button sticks to top of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have a "Reach out to..." button. It is sticky when scrolling on mobile devices:

https://dev.truecounsellor.com.au/counsellors/227/luc-devoto

I got the button to stick but the content below it jumps right up and the transition is not smooth. Any suggestions?

Comment: ask question more clear ? provide more details

Comment: So I am trying to get the "Reach out to..." button to stick to the top of the page so it doesn't get lost when scrolling down.

Comment: I have tried different scripts but I still find issues with the smoothness of the transition.

Comment: You should post a minimal working code snippet within the question, not as a link, as when that link dies this question will be useless to future users ... and we shouldn't have to parse through your website to figure what is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting div to position: fixed on scroll with jquery causes content below to jump up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232578/setting-div-to-position-fixed-on-scroll-with-jquery-causes-content-below-to-jum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing the button from where it normally is in the page with `position: static;` by setting it to `position: fixed`.

You'll probably want to use 2 different buttons instead.

BTW, you are loading bootstrap.min.js via `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS` so your users receive a "suspicious website" warning.